# Connection timeout in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I use SQL Azure in my azure asp.net website. Once in a while, the sql aerver connection doesn't open, and I see this exception message(locally and on live site):

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.

Can someone explain the cause of these, and a suitable fix for this?

Comment: Just retry the connection attempt. This is why there's Transient Fault Handling application block for Azure.

Answer (score 5):

As Sharptooth indicated in his comment; you will get transient errors more frequently on SQL Azure.  Microsoft have provided the [Transient Fault Handling Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) which caters for the common connection issues; allowing you to define a detection strategy and retry policy.

See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for a brief overview of what the transient fault handling block does and [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680891%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for a guide on how to add it to your application (Thankfully you can use NuGet).

The handling block primarily works like a try/catch block around your connection; which catches the common connection errors using a `DetectionStrategy` then retries the connection if the error matches one stated in the strategy.

We use LinqToSQL with the workspace pattern; the block wrapping our connection looks like this:

```
private const int DELAYMILLISECONDS = 250;

private const int MAXRETRIES = 10;

public static ApplicationDatabaseDataContext Create(string connectionString)
{
    var policy = new RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(
        MAXRETRIES, 
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DELAYMILLISECONDS));

    var applicationDatabaseDataContext = 
        policy.ExecuteAction(() => GetDataContext(connectionString));

    return applicationDatabaseDataContext;
}
```

We have used the block for a while now and it mitigates the majority of these issues for us.